# $E[S_4|N(2)=3]$ and $E[N(2)|S_4=2]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$, and $S_n$ the time of the $n$'th occurrence, find $E[S_4|N(2)=3]$ and $E[N(2)|S_4=2]$.

If I'm right, for $E[N(2)|S_4=2]$, it's very easily $=4$.

For $E[S_4|N(2)=3]$ = $\frac{1}{\lambda} + E[max\{U_1, U_2, U_3\}]$ where $U_1, U_2, U_3 \text{~} Unif[0,2]$

My calculate yields $E[max\{U_1, U_2, U_3\}]=\frac{3}{2}$. Therefore, $E[S_4|N(2)=3]$ = $\frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{3}{2}$.

Can someone please verify if I am correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are $U_i$s?

Comment: Uniform distribution. Each representing the arrival of individual occurrence.

Comment: But the waiting time between Poisson events is not uniform.

Comment: @zoli conditional on $n$ arrivals in time interval $(0,t]$ where the arrivals occur are uniformly distributed—more precisely the jump times of the counting process are exactly distributed as the order statistics of $n$ uniform random variables in $(0,t]$.

Comment: Nap D. Lover: Yes, thank you. My sillyness.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Under condition $N(2)=3$ random variable $S_4$ can only take values $>2$ and consequently $\mathbb E[S_4\mid N(2)=3]>2$. This is true for *every* $\lambda>0$. Observe that the expression $\frac1{\lambda}+\frac32$ does not satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M(t)$ is defined by: $$M\left(t\right)=N\left(t+2\right)-N\left(2\right)$$
then also $M(t)$ is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$.

If further we define $R_{n}$ as the time of the $n$-th occurrence then under condition $N\left(2\right)=3$:
$$R_{n}=S_{n+3}-2$$ and consequently: $$S_{4}=2+R_{1}$$

So we conclude that: $$\mathbb{E}\left[S_{4}\mid N\left(2\right)=3\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[2+R_{1}\right]=2+\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

We could say that at point $t=2$ we have observed $3$ occurrences, and then - memoryless - the process just goes on.

The waiting time from $2$ to the next occurrence is $\frac1{\lambda}$  and does not depend on $\mathbb E[S_3\mid N(2)=3]$ (as you seem to think).

Comment: I don't agree with this answer... Yes, memoryless properties apply but you don't know if the last bird arrived at t=2. It is not the most accurate expectation you can calculate if you just use $2 + \frac{1}{\lambda}$. I will come back with another example later.

Comment: Do you agree with me that $M(t)$ as defined in my answer is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$? Secondly, your answer cannot be okay. If e.g. $\lambda=4$ then it leads to $\mathbb E[S_4\mid N(2)=3]=\frac14+\frac32<2$ which is absurd, because it contradicts $N(2)=3$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for pointing that out.